# Ifelse statement inside for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a data frame for which I need to change all negative values to positive then the changed values multiply by 100 i.e. multiply all negative values by -100. I MUST use for loop and if or ifelse.
My data frame; x = factor(c("a","b","c","d","e"), y = seq(-4, 4, by = 2), z = c(3,4,-5,6,-8)

```
    x  y  z
   1 a -4  3
   2 b -2  4
   3 c  0 -5
   4 d  2  6
   5 e  4 -8
```

So far I have succeeded in changing two of the negative values but for some reason the other to didn't change.
Here is the code:

```
for(i in 2:length(df)){
  value <- df[[i]][i]
   if(value < 0){
    df[[i]][i] = value* -100
  }
}
```

The result

```
 x   y   z
1 a  -4   3
2 b 200   4
3 c   0 500
4 d   2   6
5 e   4  -8
```

as you can see the the two negative values at [2,2] and [3,3] have been multiplied by -100 but the other two have not. Can anyone help me understand why this happened?

Thanks!

Comment: Bad example if the goal is learning how to selectively change values since there is much more efficient logic available which I show in my answer. The `if` function does not work on columns. The `ifelse` or the `dplyr:if_else` functions would need to be used, or use logical indexing with "[<-". If someone is telling you that you MUST use a for loop or even worse two for loops and and if statement then they are asking you to commit two separate, major sins against the spirit of R.

Comment: The edited version will not change the `df` object because there is no assignment back to the columns of interest. There’s a further problem with using the columns themselves because that you will not be able to assign the new values back to their intended positions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the simplicity of this application of two vectorized functions `abs` and `*`to the last two columns:

```
 dfrm <- read.table(text="x  y  z
 1 a -4  3
 2 b -2  4
 3 c  0 -5
 4 d  2  6
 5 e  4 -8",head=TRUE, colClasses=c( "character", "factor", "numeric", "numeric") )
# I have no idea what your statement "z is c()" means

 dfrm[-1] <- abs(dfrm[-1])*100


> dfrm
  x   y   z
1 a 400 300
2 b 200 400
3 c   0 500
4 d 200 600
5 e 400 800
```

To answer some of your specific questions:

1. The `if` statement is not being ignore in:

```
  if(i < 0) {
    df <- df[ ,i]*-100
      {
     }
```

The value of i in the loop index will never by <0 so the expression `i,0` will always be TRUE. (That conditional really makes no sense.)

If you want to make an assignment only in those rows were the value was negative, you could assign with a logical index